# Displayed content by alphabetical order

Tags: views, forms, blocks

I have a custom content named course and each time the admin wants add a course, it is displayed in a form with all courses, my issue is it is displayed by date and I want to change by alphabet, how can I do that? please help!!

Comment: If this is a View, all you have to do is remove the current SORT that you have and add title as your sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the form with the help of a custom module, you can sort the options in the form at the time of db query before displaying them. You can do something like this.

```
$query=db_select('table name','n');//here your table name
 $query->fields('n', array('title'));//SELECT the fields from table 
 $query ->orderBy('title', 'DESC')//ORDER BY create
 $opts=$query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed();

$form['courses'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('courses'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $opts,
);
```